# бот на питоне не отвечает

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Делал по этому ролику -  https://youtu.be/eC3EOxiRGpU

Проблема в том что когда я нажимаю на кнопку start или пишу её(/start) то не какой реакции нету .(должна появиться клавиатура  а ее нету)
Если вы знаете как решить мою проблему можете пожалуйста исправить мой код + сказать что вы изменили
Код :

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ТУТ ТОКЕН БОТА')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ttt(message):

   markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

   but1 = types.KeyboardButton("1")
   but2 = types.KeyboardButton("2")
   markup.add(but1, but2)
   if message.text == "1":
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "1")
   elif message.text == "2":
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "2")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Капс = бан - такое правило действует во многих форумах. Я прибрал капс.

Answer (score 0):

Твой бот может отвечать только на сообщения "1" или "2"
Для команды "/start" используй это:

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def command_handler(message):
```

Comment: не помогло ....